# Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'UnityEngine.Sprite'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this Unity game where I have some images in my database and I need to add then to some materials. the problem is when I going to set the image to the item.icon it gives me this error

Error  CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'UnityEngine.Sprite'
Here are the class item and the code where i get the image Bytes and transform into Image.

**EDIT 1**  added the sql where I fetch the Image. I wanna add the Image to the Item.icon.

```
public class Item
{
    public string itemName;
    public Sprite icon;
}

 public List<Image> string_to_image()
{
    connString = string.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
                                             serverName, port, userName, password, databaseName);
    imagem = null;
    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
    {
        string sQL = "SELECT imagem from salva_imagem";
        using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand(sQL, conn))
        {
            byte[] productImageByte = null;
            conn.Open();
            var rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                productImageByte = (byte[])rdr["imagem"]; ;
                num_imagem++;

                if (productImageByte != null)
                {
                   ImageConverter imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
                    var pic =    imageConverter.ConvertFrom(productImageByte) as Image;
                }
            }
            rdr.Close();
        }
    }
    return imagem ?? null;
}
```

Comment: What is `imagem`? I assume it's a list of type `UnityEngine.Sprite`?

Comment: You either have to use [Sprite.Create](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html) or simply use a [RawImage](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-RawImage.html) component instead

Comment: @DavidG its a ***list<Image> imagem**

Comment: What format are your pictures?

Comment: Then it's not this code that is giving you the error...

Comment: @derHugo its .PNG

Comment: Please add the complete code for fetching the image data and how you want to set it to the Image components

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `ImageConverter` to convert bytes to a the Unity component `Image`.

Without seeing the retbof your code it's a bit hard to tell but I guess what you want to do is loading that image from a given path or url into the `sprite` of an `Image` component.

```
public void GetTexture(string url, Action<Texture> onSuccess)
{
    StartCoroutine (LoadTexture(url, onSuccess));
}

private IEnumerator LoadTexture(string url, Action<Texture> onSuccess)
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else 
    {
        onSuccess?.Invoke(((DownloadHandlerTexture)www.downloadHandler).texture);
    }
}
```

Note that `url` can also be a local file path or however you get the image from your database.

Than you can either create a `Sprite` using

```
GetTexture(pathOrUrl, OnSuccess);

private void OnSuccess(Texture texture)
{
    var tex = (Texture2D) texture;
    var newSprite = Sprite.Create(new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, tex.width, tex.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);

    // Assign it to an Image component
    imageReference.sprite = newSprite;
}
```

Or skip that and use [RawImage](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-RawImage.html) components instead. Note however that this adds drawcalls and should be avoided.

```
private void OnSuccess (Texture texture)
{
    rawImageReference.texture = texture;
}
```

Comment: I wanna load the Image from a DataBase I've done the select that gives me the bytes from the Image. Now what I want is to convert that to the Unity Sprite type.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ImageConversion.LoadImage](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.LoadImage.html). For example:

```
var myTexture2D = new Texture2D(128, 128);
ImageConversion.LoadImage(myTexture2D , myByteArray);
```

From here you can use one of the [Sprite factory methods](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html) to create a sprite from the Texture2D in the previous step:

```
var sprite = Sprite.Create(myTexture2D, new Rect(0, 0, 128, 128), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
```

This code will create a sprite using the whole texture and put the pivot point in the center.

Hope it helps.